# Docker / Symfony / MongoDB - Cannot install mongodb with PHP 5.6 FPM

Tags: php, mongodb, docker

I'm not able to install mongodb extension using php:5.6-fpm image.
What's wrong with my Dockerfile configuration ?

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man7 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim curl debconf subversion git apt-transport-https apt-utils \
    build-essential locales acl mailutils wget zip unzip htop vim \
    gnupg gnupg1 gnupg2 \
    libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libicu-dev g++

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip intl

RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

...
...
```

I have the following error when executing `docker-compose build`

```
Step 5/18 : RUN pecl install mongodb
 ---> Running in 5cd13b1b969c
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/mongodb requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0, version <= 7.99.99), installed version is 5.6.40
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that you are using wrong version of PHP, i.e. it requires you to use PHP version 7 or newer to be able to install the package.

Comment: I have to use the version 5.6 of PHP

Comment: Update : Problem solved

Comment: Please, use the answer section to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
RUN pecl install mongodb-1.7.4
```